# Python-Copy specific rows to another CSV file

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a row in one text file to another CSV file named flights2.  But all it is writing to the file is the first line, and it writes it twice.  Here is what I have.

flights.txt file:

```
Flight,DeptCity,ArrCity,DeptDate,DeptTime
975,gva,iad,2023-7-5,1140
974,iad,gva,2023-07-03,1725
```

Python script:

```
import csv

flights2 = open('flights2.csv', mode='w', newline='')

with open('flights.txt', newline='') as csvFlights:
    flights_reader = csv.DictReader(csvFlights)
    for row in flights_reader:
         fl_writer.writerow(row)

flights2.close()
```

And my flights2.csv file looks like this afterward (the top row repeated):

```
Flight,DeptCity,ArrCity,DeptDate,DeptTime
Flight,DeptCity,ArrCity,DeptDate,DeptTime
```

Why isn't it writing every row like I think it should?  Thank you.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible as is. `fl_writer` is not defined!

As for the issue, it may be because it is writing the keys of the dict. `row` in `for row in flights_reader:` is a dict, you want the values. something like `",".join(row.values())` produces the correct comma-separated row